# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

Hi all I have been getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix this as I just started learning Angular. Can someone help me with this?

**component.ts**

```
export class AdminUser implements OnInit {
Form: FormGroup;
currentUser: User;
user: Array<any> = [];
admin: Array<any> = [];
searchText: string;
id:string;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
private individualSrv: IndividualService,
private userSrv: UserService,
private router: Router
) {
let res = individualSrv.getAll();
res.then(result => {
  result.subscribe(_user => {
    this.user = _user;
  });
});
}
  navigate(path: string) {
this.router.navigate(["/admin/" + path],{
  queryParams: {id: this.currentUser.id}
});
```

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of user">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{content.fullname}}</td>
                    <td>{{content.createddate | date}}</td>
                    <td><a (click)="navigate('userSetting')"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Setting</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: `console.log(this.currentUser)?`

Comment: And where did you assign value for `this.currentUser` variable?

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of user">
  <tr>
    <td>{{content.fullname}}</td>
    <td>{{content.createddate | date}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="navigate('userSetting')"> // This is wrong
                    //<td><a (click)="navigate(content)"> // Use this instead
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Setting</a></td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Yours navigate maybe like this:

```
navigate(user) {
this.router.navigate(["/admin/" + user.path],{
  queryParams: {id: this.user.id}
});
```

Comment: Hi @phonemyatt I use "navigate('userSetting')" because I want to bring the data over to this page if I change to "navigate(content)"I won't be able to route to this page

Comment: what do you wanna achieve? do you want to put your data in query?